# Is it possible to pass a locked mutex to a spawned task?

Tags: rust, mutex, rust-tokio

I have a struct that wraps some shared state

```rust
struct Demo(Arc<Mutex<State>>);
```

I would like to return a `Result` from a function that spawns a task that indicates if the state was locked or whether the tasked was spawned successfully. What I am trying to do so far

```rust
impl Demo {
    async fn start(&self) -> Result<(), Busy> {
        let local_state = self.0.clone();
        if let Ok(state) = local_state.try_lock() {
            spawn(async move {
                state.some_function().await
            });
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(Busy)
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives

```
error[E0597]: `local_state` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:19:27
   |
18 |         let local_state = self.0.clone();
   |             ----------- binding `local_state` declared here
19 |         if let Ok(state) = local_state.try_lock() {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                           |
   |                           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                           argument requires that `local_state` is borrowed for `'static`
...
27 |     }
   |     - `local_state` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Which makes sense but I can't figure out how to fix it. Is there a way to allow a locked mutex to be passed to a spawned task? And if not, what would be the best approach to allow the busy state to be returned to the caller?

[Full minimal example here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c03317324a53e61ae12b5dedeed289b7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the tokio `Mutex` docs there is a `try_lock_owned` method that the std version doesn't have. This returns an `OwnedMutexGuard` that works for this purpose that is only available when the mutex is wrapped in an `Arc`.

The working version

```rust
impl Demo {
    async fn start(&self) -> Result<(), Busy> {
        let local_state = self.0.clone();
        if let Ok(state) = local_state.try_lock_owned() {
            spawn(async move {
                state.some_function().await
            });
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(Busy)
        }
    }
}
```